# Check in to 2 hotels at same location

Tags: hotels, accommodation, philippines

I am planning to check into 2 hotels at the same time and I am wondering if it is allowed or hotel can raise concerns if they find out.

Situation is like this, I want to stay in a dormitory as I am a solo traveller and it allows me to mingle with people but then I am a heavy snorer which in past has disrupted other people in dormitory.
So I am planning to book dormitory and a cheap accommodation of single room to sleep at a nearby location as all private room in dormitory are booked.

Any thoughts or advice on this?

Edit:

Place i am talking about is Boracay, Philipines.

Comment: The only problem I can imagine is if you're in a country where you have to register with authorities where you are staying, or the accommodation has to register for you. Such as China or Russia.

Comment: What @hippietrail wants to say is that the jurisdiction is relevant but missing.

Comment: @hippietrail Thats a good point. Place i am talking about is Boracay, Philipines. Number of people entering is restricted and people need to show place of stay for entering as per my knowledge. May i need to reach out to embassy.

Comment: @hippietrail Or Italy. 

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is allowed. Booking a hotel for the night gives the obligation to pay for it, not to use it.

If the people of the dormitory are the caring kind they might worry something happened to you, but you can easily explain to them that you are sleeping elsewhere.

You can even return for breakfast.

As mentioned in the comments your hotel may be required to report your staying there to some authorities. Sometimes so the government can track foreigners, sometimes to check people with visa whether they kept to their plans and sometimes just to charge tourist tax.

If you plan on using both hotels and both ask your passport for registration discuss the situation with one or both hotels.

Comment: It's certainly true that you can do that - people often check in with a hotel, find it unsatisfactory, and then check in a different hotel in the same night. That said, the particular pattern that OP has in mind seems uncommon enough to me that I would worry that the authorities may smell a foul play of some kind, and start to investigate.

Comment: @xLeitix the comment is a bit excessive. It is extremely unlikely you can even file a police report, let alone the authorities actually investigating.

Comment: @Nelson I was not thinking that the hotel would file a police report (they won't care). However, if a country requires hotels to register visitors I assume they have a vested interest in tracking visitors, and if they observe that the same visitor is staying in for two different nearby places for a full week - well, let's just say if I'm the authorities, I would suspect that in one of these rooms there is somebody who wants to avoid being tracked.

Comment: @xLeitix Thanks a lot for your point. I totally agree and will drop the idea of 2 hotels to avoid any such trouble. Better to trouble people dorm ;)

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut You could ask the dorm whether you can stay as a day guest, participating in activities but sleeping elsewhere.